# how to totally remove any kind of Thumbnails using Jquery FileUpload library?

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, thumbnails, jquery-file-upload

I'm using JQuery FileUpload to upload files on my server.

I need to remove any kind of thumbnails in the html area of upload, but even if i configured the javascript and php to avoid thumbnails, i still have them in two occasions:

- when i add the file, it's created a canvas with the image
- when the file is uploaded, it is created a html image with the thumbnail link

i don't want the space for thumbnails in the box, at all.
these are my configuration (i copy only the code of interest)

this is my configuration javascript

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    **previewSourceFileTypes: '',**
    url: 'tfnav?page=upload'
});
```

and this is my configuration php:

```
$this->options = array(
        'script_url' => $this->get_full_url().'/',
    'upload_dir' => $this->_hAttach->getUploadPath(),
        'upload_url' => $this->get_full_url().'/files/',
        'user_dirs' => false,
        'mkdir_mode' => 0755,
        'param_name' => 'files',
        'delete_type' => 'DELETE',
        'access_control_allow_origin' => '*',
        'access_control_allow_credentials' => false,
        'access_control_allow_methods' => array(
            'OPTIONS',
            'HEAD',
            'GET',
            'POST',
            'PUT',
            'PATCH',
            'DELETE'
        ),
        'access_control_allow_headers' => array(
            'Content-Type',
            'Content-Range',
            'Content-Disposition'
        ),
        'download_via_php' => false,
        // Defines which files can be displayed inline when downloaded:
        **'inline_file_types' => '',**
        // Defines which files (based on their names) are accepted for upload:
        'accept_file_types' => '/.+$/i',
        ....
```

but these configurations are not enough, how can i remove them?
thanks a lot in advance

Comment: A solution is to remove the two `<td class="preview">` tag in the html template of the box. so no thumbnails will be displayed. furthermore it should be removed or commented the php function to create the thumbnails. am I right?

Answer (score 2):

inside UploadHandler.php

comment all inside 'image_versions'

```
'image_versions' => array()
```

or you could do this

```
 $upload_handler = new UploadHandler(array(
    'image_versions' => array() // no image versions
));
```